# Change ELF Endian Data Format

Tags: compiler-construction, endianness, elf, object-files, dwarf

I am trying to edit some software to work with both Big and Little Endian ELF/DWARF files. In order to this, I think it would be a good idea to have both a Little and Big ELF file of the same data. I am using a simple program in a compiler to create an ELF Object file, however the object file is formatted always in the endianness of the architecture of the chip I am using. Is there a way to obtain both endianness for a single program on a single chip?

Thanks.

Comment: Might depend on the architecture. For e.g, ARM can operate in both little and big endian. It might be worth checking in your compiler manual as well if you can override the endian-ness of the binary using an explicit compiler option